# creating a define only used by eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have project that was created in another IDE that is build for a specific microcontroler. In the code `far`is used quite often and it is comprehended by the IDE and compiler.

I would like to use eclipse to edit the code, because it is more convinient to use. But it generates a lot of warnings and errors in the editor because he can not resolve the `far`.

I could create a macro `#define far`, but I would have to remove it when I want to compile the code. I don't compile with eclipse, because getting the compiler to work there is cumbersome and might introduce problems.

So is there a possibility that eclipse itself can handle the `far` for its syntax check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I searched a bit more I found an answer here:
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/72375/

Go to the menu:

Project -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> Path and Symbols ->
Symbols

and add a Symbol called `far` with the value `/* */`.

I just left the value empty and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that involves modifying your code rather than the project settings would be:

```
#ifdef __CDT_PARSER__
#define far
#endif
```

`__CDT_PARSER__` is a macro that is automatically defined by CDT's parser when it processes your code, but not by any compiler.

Comment: This is a viable solution. I still prefer not to do so, because it will be visible to other people working with the project and might confuse them. (Or I would have least be careful not to merge it). It would have the advantage that it works on every PC without setup.